# DateTimePicker: setting a range of dates and a third date afterwards

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I need to set a range of dates using the plugin [DateTimePicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) plus a specific third date after this range.

This is the code I have so far:

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="startdate" class="control-label">Start Date</label>
  <div class="input-group date" id="startdate">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon text-primary"></span>
    </span>
  </div><!-- input-group -->
</div><!-- form-group -->

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="enddate" class="control-label">End Date</label>
  <div class="input-group date" id="enddate">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon text-primary"></span>
    </span>
  </div><!-- input-group -->
</div><!-- form-group -->

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="thirddate" class="control-label">Third Date</label>
  <div class="input-group date" id="thirddate">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon text-primary"></span>
    </span>
  </div><!-- input-group -->
</div><!-- form-group -->
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(function () {

    //Enablabling linked pickers
    $('#startdate,#enddate,#thirddate').datetimepicker({
      format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
      useCurrent: false
    });

    //Setting the range of dates
    $("#startdate").on("dp.change", function (e) {
      $('#enddate').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
    });
    $("#enddate").on("dp.change", function (e) {
      $('#startdate').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
    });

    //Setting a third date in the future after the range
    $("#thirddate").on("dp.change", function (e) {
      $('#enddate').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
    });
});
```

The DateTimePickers for the range are working fine, but the third one is not, since it does not take the minDate value properly.

Comment: btw don't you have a typo in $("startdate")? Shouldn't it be $("#startdate")?

Comment: Thanks, I edited the typo. Unfortunately that's not the reason, in my source code it was OK.

Comment: Can you post your HTML markup? And what should happen if the third date is selected?

Comment: @PhaniKumarM got it! The third datetimepicker allows you to add any date but the past ones

Comment: @nicozica When you select third date, you are setting min date to end date and is working fine. What is the problem?

Comment: @PhaniKumarM the third datetimepicker should not allow the user to set dates before the selected range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps. The third date picker allows date selection after end date.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Enablabling linked pickers
        $('#startdate,#enddate,#thirddate').datetimepicker({
            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
            useCurrent: false
        });

        //Setting the range of dates
        $("#startdate").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#enddate').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
        });
        $("#enddate").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#startdate').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
            $('#thirddate').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date); //Added this 
        });

        /* Remove this */

        //Setting a third date in the future after the range
        //$("#thirddate").on("dp.change", function (e) {
        //   $('#enddate').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
        //});
    })
</script>
```